# Является ли email адрес asd@asd валидным?

Tags: html, email, валидация

```
<form action="index.php">
    <input type="email" required="required">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Данная конструкция пропускает email типа asd@asd
Являются ли такие адреса валидными?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Тут есть ссылки на стандарты - вот то что в них написано - то валидное

Answer (score 1):

У нас внутри предприятия приняты такие ящики: user@department. Поэтому такой адрес был бы валидным, можно обращаться и посредством user@computer, в т.ч. user@localhost . Но если речь о глобальной сети, не валиден, за исключением каких-то очень частных случаев.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/
Проблема возникла с этим плагином... после обновления он стал пропускать email типа asd@asd... ссылаясь на спецификации

Comment: В частности вот сюда https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address

Comment: Валидность не зависит от размера сети. Адрес вполне может быть валидным, но никем не обслуживаться за неимением у почтового домена MX-записи, а то и DNS-серверов вообще.